# Updating list stored in hash table

Tags: scheme, racket

I have an immutable hash table that contains a series of lists as values. I wrote a procedure so I could add an item to one of the lists, returning a new hash:

```
(define (update hash key item)
  (hash-set hash
            key
            (cons item
                  (hash-ref hash key)))))
```

This seems to work fine, but feels awkward and verbose. Is there a built-in procedure that accomplishes this, or maybe a more idiomatic way of achieving the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

This is as simple as it can get:

```
(define (update hash key item)
  (hash-update hash key (curry cons item) '()))
```

Explanation:

- [`hash-update`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt%29._hash-update%29%29) returns a *new* hash with an updated value for the given key - or you can use [`hash-update!`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt%29._hash-update%21%29%29) to modify the hash in-place.
- `hash` and `key` are self-explanatory.
- The third parameter is an *updater* procedure which receives as a parameter the old value, in this case it's a procedure that `cons`es a new item (because the old value was a list); this is set as the new value for the given key.
- The last parameter is the default value to be returned in case the key was not found, *before* calling the *updater* procedure.

Comment: Thank you, this is much more concise. This also allowed me to remove a second procedure and some conditional logic .... basically, I wrote something else to update the hash in the case that the key did not already exist. Your version handles both cases.

Comment: Great! I'm glad this was useful :)

Comment: How can I use the updater for inserting into a set ? Something like (curryr set-add! 1)

Comment: @ApoorvJain consider posting it as a new question. And wow, you've been a member for 6 full years and never accepted a single question! I'm appalled.